# NSStatusBar item glow without the glow image on Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

How can i make something like this glow on a status bar item?

[image]

I know that i can do that with another png, but i have seen some other applications where they only have the black icon of the statusbar, no glow.

How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just draw your image with a white drop shadow (some blur radius, no offset) in a custom view. [`NSShadow`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSShadow_Class/Reference/Reference.html) makes this very easy to do.